# how can I change dialog box's title color?

Tags: android, colors, styles, dialog

I use dialog box in my app. But I want to change my dialog box title's color. How can I handle it. Thanks...

Comment: I cant handle it and I changed my app thanks everyone for your interest and advise:D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

U can create an xml as ur wish.. then in dialog inflate the layout..

```
    LayoutInflater factory2 = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View coloredChangedView= factory2.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);
//do other things...
.setView(coloredChangedView);
```

This way u can customised ur dialog..

Answer (score 0):

You can try to extend the default theme and use it in your activity. You need to extend the Theme.Dialog style. find example [here](http://www.anddev.org/custom_theme_dialog___transparent_background-t7300.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `AlertDialog` there is a `setCustomTitle(View)` function you can use (also in the Builder).